# SEO: How to get rid of the webpages titles below the main link url on Google

Tags: hyperlink, dns, seo, title

Recently I changed my website which now is hosted on a different server (the previous server hosted by another company is not available anymore).
Everything is different on my new website including the content, the layout, the design and, most important here, the url's format.
The only thing I kept is my domain name which has been redirected toward the new server.

Keeping the same domain name is the issue:

The problem is that when I make a search about my website on Google, the main link displayed is ok but below this link, there are 4 titles corresponding to 4 sections of my previous website.

Clicking on them will lead to previous url's that don't exist anymore.
You get a kind of cached result with no css and the users are complaining a lot about that.

I opened an account on "Google webmasters" and I declared a brand new sitemap.xml and asked for a new Googlebots crawling (three times already).

It's been a week now and the titles below the general link on Google remain the same.

How can I get rid of these?

On "Google webmasters" I tried to "ban" the url's of these titles. It kinda works but not as I expected: The titles remain there but there is no more description below them (which doesn't solve my issue, it just makes it uglier).

Another difference is that one of these links finally disappeared … but another outdated section link has taken its place. It can go like this forever as there are too many possible links to ban with no certainty of result.

What I would like is just keep the main link on Google and get rid of these "sub" titles. At least the old ones.

PS: I never asked for these titles in the first place. they just appeared a long time ago.
I don't mind getting the new sections there but certainly not the old ones.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would block the old site's content with a robot.txt to prevent any crawls by cached sitemap.xmls.
If you have a site with a decent amount of SEO traffic, I'd create an htcaccess 301 redirect of the most important results.

It can take some time until your de-indexing will start. I've waited about 2 weeks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Like I said, the previous website and server are not available anymore. I can't redirect anything because these pages don't exist anymore. The same for the htaccess file: the previous server is out of reach. All I have now is the Google services and the new server (the previous server hosting was a real con). That is the catch. Strange that Google don't handle this kind of situations where the domain name is the same but not the content. When it comes to average businesses, it can be a disaster.